# SQL multiple select query with different field names?

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem with a query I'm trying to run. The query gets 3 separate select queries (each of which work by themselves) but I'm getting stuck on concatenating them all into a single result. 2 of the selects contain the same fields, but the 3rd contains different fields, and I wondered if there was anything I could do instead of splitting the query up into 2 separate ones. At the minute it's giving me error 1241.

It works fine when I union the 1st and 3rd select statements together, but obviously the middle query has different field names and data coming out. Just wasn't sure if you could extract sql data into an array of arrays, would have been easier!

cheers, Andrew

```
SELECT( 
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', `cas_users`.`first_name`, `cas_users`.`last_name`) AS `name`, `cas_users`.`email`, `cas_users`.`meta`, `cas_users`.`id` 
    FROM `cas_users` 
    INNER JOIN `cas_connected` 
    ON `cas_connected`.`freelancer_hash` = `cas_users`.`hash` 
    WHERE `cas_connected`.`employer_hash` = 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35' 
    AND `cas_connected`.`stage` = '0' 
    AND `cas_users`.`expiry` > '1331165519'
) AS `c_p`, ( 
    SELECT `name`, `email`, `phone`, `invited` 
    FROM `cas_not_connected` 
    WHERE `employer_hash` = 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35' 
) AS `nc`, ( 
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', `cas_users`.`first_name`, `cas_users`.`last_name`) AS `name`, `cas_users`.`email`, `cas_users`.`meta`, `cas_users`.`id` 
    FROM `cas_users`
    INNER JOIN `cas_connected` 
    ON `cas_connected`.`freelancer_hash` = `cas_users`.`hash` 
    WHERE `cas_connected`.`employer_hash` = 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35' 
    AND `cas_connected`.`stage` = '1' 
    AND `cas_users`.`expiry` < '1331165519' 
) AS `c_e`
```

EDIT:

This is the code I got working in the end, took advantage of the full outer join workaround. Maybe overkill, but ensures only 1 database trip to get all the data I needed. The left_outer_join and right_outer_join can be anything as long as they are guaranteed NOT to match.:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', `cas_users`.`first_name`, `cas_users`.`last_name`) AS `name`, `cas_users`.`email` AS `email1`, `cas_users`.`meta`, `cas_users`.`id` AS `id1`, `cas_connected`.`stage` 
    FROM `cas_users` 
    INNER JOIN `cas_connected` 
    ON `cas_connected`.`freelancer_hash` = `cas_users`.`hash` 
    WHERE `cas_connected`.`employer_hash` = 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35' 
    AND `cas_connected`.`stage` = '0' 
    AND `cas_users`.`expiry` > '1331173687' 
    UNION 
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', `cas_users`.`first_name`, `cas_users`.`last_name`) AS `name`, `cas_users`.`email` AS `email1`, `cas_users`.`meta`, `cas_users`.`id` AS `id1`, `cas_connected`.`stage` FROM `cas_users` 
    INNER JOIN `cas_connected` 
    ON `cas_connected`.`freelancer_hash` = `cas_users`.`hash` 
    WHERE `cas_connected`.`employer_hash` = 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35' 
    AND `cas_connected`.`stage` = '1' 
    AND `cas_users`.`expiry` < '1331173687' ) 
AS `conn` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `cas_not_connected` 
ON `conn`.`id1` = `cas_not_connected`.`name` 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', `cas_users`.`first_name`, `cas_users`.`last_name`) AS `name`, `cas_users`.`email` AS `email1`, `cas_users`.`meta`, `cas_users`.`id` AS `id1`, `cas_connected`.`stage` 
    FROM `cas_users` 
    INNER JOIN `cas_connected` 
    ON `cas_connected`.`freelancer_hash` = `cas_users`.`hash` 
    WHERE `cas_connected`.`employer_hash` = 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35' 
    AND `cas_connected`.`stage` = '0' 
    AND `cas_users`.`expiry` > '1331173687' 
    UNION 
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', `cas_users`.`first_name`, `cas_users`.`last_name`) AS `name`, `cas_users`.`email` AS `email1`, `cas_users`.`meta`, `cas_users`.`id` AS `id1`, `cas_connected`.`stage` FROM `cas_users` 
    INNER JOIN `cas_connected` 
    ON `cas_connected`.`freelancer_hash` = `cas_users`.`hash` 
    WHERE `cas_connected`.`employer_hash` = 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35' 
    AND `cas_connected`.`stage` = '1' 
    AND `cas_users`.`expiry` < '1331173687' ) 
AS `conn` 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `cas_not_connected` 
ON `conn`.`id1` = `cas_not_connected`.`name`
```

Comment: You can also fake those fields with empty values, but this will probaly not give you what you want. To explain what I ment: If you have a two column table that you want to union with a three column table use a constant value for that column. Like: SELECT id, name, 'value' AS age from table

Answer (score 0):

Since you have different fields in your 2nd query, a UNION won't do.  You'll have to put these beside the other columns.  I keep this rule in mind....
UNION puts data on top of other data. JOIN puts data next to other data.

So what I think you want to end up with is columns from the first and last query with the columns from the middle query tacked on to the end for both of those result sets.

So I'm unioning the first and last queries together, then joining that result set to the 2nd query via the employer_hash.  I am using a UNION ALL just so the record counts make sense (ie query1 + query2 = new query), though that may not be what you want.

Also doing a left outer join so the 2nd query doesn't dictate which records show up in the result set.  This may need some fine tuning, but should get you where you want to go.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', `cas_users`.`first_name`, `cas_users`.`last_name`) AS `name`, `cas_users`.`email`, `cas_users`.`meta`, `cas_users`.`id`, employer_hash
    FROM `cas_users` 
    INNER JOIN `cas_connected` 
    ON `cas_connected`.`freelancer_hash` = `cas_users`.`hash` 
    WHERE `cas_connected`.`employer_hash` = 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35' 
    AND `cas_connected`.`stage` = '0' 
    AND `cas_users`.`expiry` > '1331165519'
 UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', `cas_users`.`first_name`, `cas_users`.`last_name`) AS `name`, `cas_users`.`email`, `cas_users`.`meta`, `cas_users`.`id` 
    FROM `cas_users`
    INNER JOIN `cas_connected` 
    ON `cas_connected`.`freelancer_hash` = `cas_users`.`hash` 
    WHERE `cas_connected`.`employer_hash` = 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35' 
    AND `cas_connected`.`stage` = '1' 
    AND `cas_users`.`expiry` < '1331165519' 
) AS `c_p_c_e`
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
    SELECT `name`, `email`, `phone`, `invited`, employer_hash
    FROM `cas_not_connected` 
    WHERE `employer_hash` = 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35' 
) AS `nc`, on c_p.employer_hash = nc.employer_hash
```

Comment: Hey Jody, thanks for the suggestion, I tweaked your code a little bit so it was working, but alas not what I was after. I think (after a look around google) I was after a full outer join so that I could get all information in 1 database trip, but there is no full outer join in mysql! I think it's probably safest to just get 2 database queries than try and fit everything into 1!

Answer (score -1):

You'll probably want to use the UNION keyword

```
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', `cas_users`.`first_name`, `cas_users`.`last_name`) AS `name`, `cas_users`.`email`, `cas_users`.`meta`, `cas_users`.`id` 
    FROM `cas_users` 
    INNER JOIN `cas_connected` 
    ON `cas_connected`.`freelancer_hash` = `cas_users`.`hash` 
    WHERE `cas_connected`.`employer_hash` = 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35' 
    AND `cas_connected`.`stage` = '0' 
    AND `cas_users`.`expiry` > '1331165519'
UNION
    SELECT `name`, `email`, `phone`, `invited` 
    FROM `cas_not_connected` 
    WHERE `employer_hash` = 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35' 
UNION
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', `cas_users`.`first_name`, `cas_users`.`last_name`) AS `name`, `cas_users`.`email`, `cas_users`.`meta`, `cas_users`.`id` 
    FROM `cas_users`
    INNER JOIN `cas_connected` 
    ON `cas_connected`.`freelancer_hash` = `cas_users`.`hash` 
    WHERE `cas_connected`.`employer_hash` = 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35' 
    AND `cas_connected`.`stage` = '1' 
    AND `cas_users`.`expiry` < '1331165519'
```

This assumes that the columns are all of the same type.  It looks as though the second column contains some different fields.

Comment: Yeah the second column is pulling similar but different data out, I wasn't sure if there was a way to store the results in an array of arrays, as Mongo does.